# What is the graph of $y = \sin n$ and why is it different from the graph of $y = \sin x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have downloaded a book about Calculus from [MIT OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu). In that book, there is a section "A Thousand points of Light". (You can download the relevant section from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BytxARWilliKdFpVeDRGcVZ1dFU/edit?usp=sharing).)

In that section, it is written that the graph of $y=\sin x$ is different from the graph of $y=\sin n$.

[image: Book Image]

However, I cannot understand this thing.  Why will the graph of $y=\sin n$ be different from the graph of $y=\sin x$? How can you change a graph by changing a variable in the function? And how have they plotted the graph in the book?

Comment: the point here is that $n$ stands for a natural number. So you only have natural numbers on the x-axis.

Comment: @J.B. Oh.. Thanks. That was confusing me very much. How did you come to know this?

Comment: @Kartik You can tell because the second graph is not continuous i.e. the dots are not connected by a line as opposed to the first graph where they are.

Comment: $n$ usually stands for a natural number and you can see in the picture, that he did not plot the whole sine curve, but only some points of it.

Comment: @gekkostate I think you got that wrong. The first picture only appears like that, because there are more points, not sure though.

Comment: @J.B. I stand corrected. In general, however, is not true that if points on a graph are not connected then it could indicate that natural numbers are being used? For example, when we look at the graph of sums, the points aren't connected indicating that $n$ in the sum is a natural number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between your first and second graph is the fact $y = \sin x$ uses $\mathbb{R}$ as its domain and $y = \sin n$ uses $\mathbb{N}$ as it's domain. Furthermore, the points on the second graph are not connected which implies that the second graph is not continuous *and* via inspection, you can notice that the $x$-axis only has natural numbers.